# Centos 6.7 Partitioning command

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

The current storage on the server is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       118G  109G  3.0G  98% /
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vdc        118G   40G   73G  36% /backup
/usr/tmpDSK     4.0G  137M  3.7G   4% /tmp
/dev/vdd        118G   60M  112G   1% /new
```

What I am looking for is merging /dev/vdd (/new) into dev/vda1 (/) without affecting dev/vda's data. Is there a safe command to perform that?

note:  that there's no data yet in /dev/vdd or /new.

Output for dev directory:

```
block            loop6               ram2      tty16  tty41  ttyS0
btrfs-control    loop7               ram3      tty17  tty42  ttyS1
bus              lp0                 ram4      tty18  tty43  ttyS2
char             lp1                 ram5      tty19  tty44  ttyS3
console          lp2                 ram6      tty2   tty45  urandom
core             lp3                 ram7      tty20  tty46  usbmon0
cpu              MAKEDEV             ram8      tty21  tty47  usbmon1
cpu_dma_latency  mapper              ram9      tty22  tty48  vcs
crash            mcelog              random    tty23  tty49  vcs1
disk             mem                 raw       tty24  tty5   vcs2
fb               net                 root      tty25  tty50  vcs3
fb0              network_latency     rtc       tty26  tty51  vcs4
fd               network_throughput  rtc0      tty27  tty52  vcs5
full             null                shm       tty28  tty53  vcs6
fuse             nvram               snapshot  tty29  tty54  vcsa
hidraw0          oldmem              stderr    tty3   tty55  vcsa1
hpet             port                stdin     tty30  tty56  vcsa2
hugepages        ppp                 stdout    tty31  tty57  vcsa3
hvc0             ptmx                systty    tty32  tty58  vcsa4
input            pts                 tty       tty33  tty59  vcsa5
kmsg             ram0                tty0      tty34  tty6   vcsa6
log              ram1                tty1      tty35  tty60  vda
loop0            ram10               tty10     tty36  tty61  vda1
loop1            ram11               tty11     tty37  tty62  vdb
loop2            ram12               tty12     tty38  tty63  vdc
loop3            ram13               tty13     tty39  tty7   vdd
loop4            ram14               tty14     tty4   tty8                 vga_arbiter
loop5            ram15               tty15     tty40  tty9   zero
```

Parted Output

```
sudo parted /dev/vda1
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/vda1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) u s                                                              
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/vda1: 251524831s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags
```

Comment: Are you using LVM ?

Comment: I am not really sure. It's been provided by the hosting provider.

Comment: Both are VirtIO

Comment: Can you try to run 'lvscan' and post the output? If your root is a logical volume it's fairly easy to extend.

Comment: No Output is given. Also tried sudo pvscan and got : No matching physical volumes found

Comment: Volume type is GPT

Answer (score 0):

Considering that /dev/vda1 is mounted as root, there is no LVM, Which means that it's really hard to do it.

You will need to create a lvm on vdd, move your root partition over there, modify fstab and grub to boot from the new partition and reboot. After reboot you will add vda1 to the previous created lvm.

I wouldn't try it in your place, since it requires some advance linux knowledge and some prayers to your god to make it work